# Heredity in MySQL or foreign key related more than one table?

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys, relational-database

Expose my problem, I have two different tables '*user*' and '*client*'. I want to start storing each session attempt to statistical control. Table '*login_attempts*' contains just who does the login, on what date and time and from that IP.

The problem is to relate the '*login_attempts*' to '*user*' and '*client*' at a time to avoid creating a table '*login_attempts*' for each entity table.

The problem is not the relationship itself, but that table discriminate both the stored identifier belongs.

I had thought about doing something like:

[image: EER]

Table '*login_attempts*' would store the identifier of the entity and also the particular register of the entity that performs at logon. In turn, each record of each entity would have a field that would store the identifier of the entity to which belongs (registered in another table) in order to discriminate between one or the other.

I do not know if there is a simpler way to do it and avoid data redundancy.

I do not know if I have explained well. Any help is good, thank you all.